# WP-CLI - Return posts with matching meta key

Tags: wp-cli

I am using the WP-CLI to manage my sites.  I can run the following command

```
wp post list --fields=ID,mycustomfield

 ID   |  mycustomfield
-----------------------
 1    |  active
 2    |  active
 3    |  disabled
 4    |  active
```

I am trying to narrow this list down by only returning those which has **mycustomfield** as active

Any ideas how I can do this?

Answer (score 2):

Managed to figure this out, you can pass **--meta_key** and **--meta_compare** arguments like this...

```
wp post list --fields=ID,mycustomfield --meta_key=mycustomfield '--meta_compare=active'

ID   |  mycustomfield
-----------------------
 1    |  active
 2    |  active
 4    |  active
```

Comment: Looks like this is no more working

Comment: should be meta_value not meta_compare

Answer (score 2):

You may pass any standard `WP_Query` arguments as flags to the `wp post list` command.

`--<field>=<value>`

In your example you would use the meta query arguments.

`wp post list --fields=ID,mycustomfield --meta_key=mycustomfield --meta_value=active`

[Vague documentation is here.](https://developer.wordpress.org/cli/commands/post/list/#options)

Comment: This is the one that works! Thank you.